# Difference between defining isolated scope variable for angular directive in {} and in link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In angular directive, I know I can assign isolated scope, but I need to add '=' or '@' or '&' to define variable in {} while I don't have to do that in link, for example:

```
 scope: {
   foo:'=foo',
   bar:'@bar'
 }
```

this works

```
link: function($scope, $element){
  $scope.foo = 'foo';
  $scope.bar = 'bar';
}
```

this works too (the link function is in directive)

```
 scope: {
   foo:'foo',
   bar:'bar'
 }
```

this doesn't work! because I didn't add '=' or '@' or '&'

So my question is, the $scope in link should be the same with $scope:{}, both are the same isolated scope, but why I can define variable in link without adding '=' or '@' or '&'?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the link property, you're just dealing with directive's isolated scope. With the scope property, you're defining how the attributes on the element (in parent scope) are imported into your isolated scope. They serve different purposes.

The =, @, and & prefixes define how the attributes are interpreted when importing them into your isolated scope:

1. modelParent: '=modelIsolate' - Imports a model into your isolated scope by establishing a two-way model binding between the model defined in parent scope (modelParent) and the model defined on your isolated scope (modelIsolate).  Here, the modelParent attribute on the directive is interpreted as a model.
2. attrib1: '@attrib1' - Imports a string into your isolated scope by evaluating the attribute value as a string.  The attribute may have interpolated expressions.  For example, if you pass 'hello {{ name }}' as an attribute to your directive where name is bound to 'James' in parent scope, then what will be bound to 'attrib1' in your isolated scope will be $scope.attrib1 = 'hello James'.  When the 'name' binding changes (i.e. from James to Mike) then 'attrib1' in your isolated scope will be automatically updated.  For this reason, @ binding is sometimes referred to as 1-way binding.  Personally, I like to think of it as just strings with support for interpolation.
3. express: '&express' - Imports an expression into your isolated scope that can be evaluated in parent scope.  This is commonly used to execute a function that exists in parent scope, from within your directive's isolated scope. For example, if you have a click handler defined in your parent scope: `$scope.onclick = function() {};` and you pass this into your directive: `<directive attrib1="onclick" />`, you can call the function from within your directive: template: `'<div ng-click="attrib1()" />'`.

All three methods import scope variables from the parent scope into your isolated scope. But depending on how you want to interpret the directive attributes, you will prefer one over the others.

Comment: Yup I know the usage of '= @ &', but my question is that angular forces me to add '= @ &' in $scope = {}, but why I don't have to add these prefix in the variables definition in link function?